# How to preserve DHCP server settings when migrating from Lion Server to Mountain Lion Server?

Tags: macos, upgrade, osx-server, server.app, network

I understand that DHCP server features will be "[removed](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5412?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)" from OS X Server with Mountain Lion and that there will be no way to manage these using the only remaining app for managing server features (Server).

However, I also gather that it is [possible](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/the-server-simplified-a-power-users-guide-to-os-x-server/) to not only preserve DHCP server settings, but [continue to manage them](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/running-dhcp-on-mountain-lion-server/) under Mountain Lion Server, if one is careful to follow certain steps. But it's not entirely clear exactly what those steps are, and I don't want to undertake an upgrade at the risk of loosing (even for a second) critical settings and functionality (my entire network has static IP addresses assigned by Lion Server).

How can I ensure that I do not loose my DHCP server settings, and can continue to manage them, through an upgrade from Lion to Mountain Lion Server? In particular, what are the steps to *save* my existing settings in Lion and have them used *throughout* the upgrade process to Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation is actually [simpler](http://www.amsys.co.uk/2012/blog/dhcp-dhcp-wherefore-art-thou-dhcp/) than some references make it seem. As [Apple states](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5412?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US):

> If you enabled DHCP (only) in Server Admin in Lion Server, your configuration will be preserved when you upgrade or migrate to OS X Server (Mountain Lion).

Moreover, the Server app now provides a (very limited, but sufficient) user interface for controlling DHCP.

Comment: Warning: This [may not in fact work](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/84263/4395) as advertised by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused.

[image]

This is from ML server.  Next, as I understand it, you CAN NOT run Internet sharing WITH DHCP turned on.  You do one or the other.  If you turn on Internet Sharing it will supersede the DHCP configuration.

Comment: Wow: that "important" note in the documentation was added since my answer. Good catch (and good thing I still haven't "upgraded"). If you can sort out what the full story is (now the docs leave me wondering), with the steps I need to take to get from Mountain Lion running DHCP to Lion running DHCP with all settings preserved, I may be on the track to an answer.

Comment: I migrated from Lion to Mountain Lion with DHCP intact.  Are you comfortable explaining the configuration you are using in a public forum?  Is it just one network?  Did you do anything unusual in the config?  If you want me to try out a config for you I'd be happy to do it.

Comment: This works fine now that DHCP is restored to the administration app (though it's too bad that the dumbed-down app itself has such a bad UI). I'm hoping I can find some third party tools that are better.